# Trying to copy Pandas DataFrame rows X Times but different depending on a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**df**

```
    Name Run ID1 ID2
0    A   18  100 500
1    B   19  150 550
2    C   18  200 600
3    D   15  250 650
```

I then have a variable named **max_runs = 20**
What I want to do is get the data into this format below.  Essentially copy each unique row max_runs - df['Run'] times

**df_output**

```
     Name Run ID1 ID2
1     A   19  100 500
2     A   20  100 500
3     B   20  150 550
4     C   19  200 600
5     C   20  200 600
6     D   16  250 650
7     D   17  250 650
8     D   18  250 650
9     D   19  250 650
10    D   20  250 650
```

Thanks for any help and let me know if I need to explain further

Comment: Could you provide df data in a format that would easily allows us to use it in python (ie a csv format or better yet, directly as a python statement `df = pd.DataFrame(.....)`. It helps us help you if your code is immediately reproducible.

Comment: @JayMody copy the text data and use `df=pd.read_clipboard()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Holy crap, that's a really neat trick. Thanks!

Comment: @QuangHoang I was shocked by this trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repeat` to repeat the rows and `assign` to modify the new run:

```
(df.loc[df.index.repeat(20-df.Run)]
   .assign(Run=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(x.Run+1))
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   index Name  Run  ID1  ID2
0      0    A   19  100  500
1      0    A   20  100  500
2      1    B   20  150  550
3      2    C   19  200  600
4      2    C   20  200  600
5      3    D   16  250  650
6      3    D   17  250  650
7      3    D   18  250  650
8      3    D   19  250  650
9      3    D   20  250  650
```

Comment: Wow thanks a ton.  Pandas is an amazing package, appreciate the help..it worked perfectly.  You even edited my post like 30 seconds after i posted before I could edit it so thanks for that too. 
Just one quick thing. Is there a way to get rid of the 'index' column now? I tried dropping it and it would give me a "not found in axis" error